# Google maps fragment crashes when clicked twice from navigation drawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer with three list items. The first one brings up a fragment with a text view and the second one brings up a fragment with a map. It works when I click on the option to bring up the map fragment and it works when I switch to the first fragment again but it crashes when I try to click on the map fragment again.

My map fragment class looks like:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

GoogleMap map;
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    FragmentTwo f = new FragmentTwo();

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null,false);
    if (root != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) root.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(root);
    }
    try {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));


}}
```

My xml looks like:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
View root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null,false);
```

and in the MainActivity Make The Initialze

```
FragmentTwo f = new FragmentTwo();
```

In the Oncreate 
and  when you need to swap to this fragment u can use

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, f).commit();
```